# Unable to run Flutter App on iOS when using Firebase. Android seems to be working but iOS throws multiple errors

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter

So I followed the instructions on adding Firebase to Flutter and although things work on Android, I am unable to build on the ios emulator. I get some xcode errors. I have tried deleting both ios/Pods directory and the Podfile.lock file, then using the flutter clean command. But I still get these errors. I have tried doing research but nothing I have found has helped. Here are the errors i get when I try to test on the iOS emulator.

Thank you in advance for the help.

**Errors From Flutter Run:**

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 12 Pro Max in debug mode...
Running pod install...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           130.2s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2021-03-26 18:45:52.768 xcodebuild[15465:79135]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-001945163408001E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f963f7d3f80>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f963b713cc0>{number = 3, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    2021-03-26 18:45:52.947 xcodebuild[15465:79134]  DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTiOSFrameworks/DVTiOSFrameworks-17705/DTDeviceKitBase/DTDKRemoteDeviceData.m:371
    Details:  (null) deviceType from 00008101-001945163408001E was NULL when -platform called.
    Object:   <DTDKMobileDeviceToken: 0x7f963f7d3f80>
    Method:   -platform
    Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7f963f725360>{number = 7, name = (null)}
    Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/dev/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:5:
    In file included from <module-includes>:1:
    In file included from /Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
    In file included from /Users/dev/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.2/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:11:
    /Users/dev/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-1.0.2/ios/Classes/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h' [-Werror,-Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module]
    #import <FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h>
            ^
    1 error generated.
    /Users/dev/development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-1.0.1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.m:5:9: fatal error: could not build module 'firebase_core'
    #import <firebase_core/FLTFirebasePluginRegistry.h>
     ~~~~~~~^
    2 errors generated.
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro Max.
```

**Errors from Xcode:**

```
/Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_core/firebase_core.framework/Headers/FLTFirebasePlugin.h:9:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'firebase_core.FLTFirebasePlugin': '/Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseCore/FirebaseCore.h'

/Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/firebase_auth/firebase_auth.framework/Headers/FLTFirebaseAuthPlugin.h:12:9: Could not build module 'firebase_core'

/Users/dev/AndroidStudioProjects/aul/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:8:9: Could not build module 'firebase_auth'
```

Answer (score 0):

In my iOS/Runner/AppDelegate.swift file I was initiating Firebase there, which is not needed. I also added the the firebase pod plugins to my Podfile. Once I removed these things it started to work.